# website not able to become responsive in django

Tags: html, css, django, mobile, responsive-design

I want to make my html code mobile responsive, but it's not working as I expected.
I tried `@media` and `rem` instead of `px` but the results are not as expected, the things are overlapping on each other and info is going out of the main `div`s white space on the right side of the screen

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.part1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.tt {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  animation: slideInLeftTt 1s ease forwards;
  /* Animation for tt */
}

@keyframes slideInLeftTt {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.txt2 {
  font-size: 35px;
  animation: slideInUpTxt2 1s ease forwards;
  /* Animation for txt2 */
}

@keyframes slideInUpTxt2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.txt {
  font-size: 64px;
  animation: slideInUpTxt 1s ease forwards;
  /* Animation for txt */
}

@keyframes slideInUpTxt {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.txt1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  animation: slideInUpTxt1 1s ease forwards;
  /* Animation for txt1 */
}

@keyframes slideInUpTxt1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.A1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: fit-content;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Baskerville Old Face', serif;
}

.pv {
  margin-top: 140px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}

.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.logo-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 65%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 10px solid #808080;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
}

.part2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* Change height to min-height */
  background-color: #fff6f2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Baskerville Old Face', serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Hide content overflow */
}

.part2b {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
}

.part2a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.qq {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.q2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.q3 {
  font-size: 80px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.bg3 {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.circle-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  /* Adjust to your desired position */
  left: 65%;
  /* Adjust to your desired position */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 17px solid #fff6f2;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.animate-slide-right {
  animation: slideRight 1s forwards;
  opacity: 0;
  /* Initially hide the elements */
}

.animate-slide-left {
  animation: slideLeft 1s forwards;
  opacity: 0;
  /* Initially hide the elements */
}

.animate-slide-up {
  animation: slideUp 1s forwards;
  opacity: 0;
  /* Initially hide the elements */
}

.animate-slide-right-circle {
  animation: slideRight 1s forwards;
  opacity: 0;
  /* Initially hide the elements */
}

.animate-slide-left-bg {
  animation: slideLeft 1s forwards;
  opacity: 0;
  /* Initially hide the elements */
}

@keyframes slideRight {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes slideLeft {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes slideUp {
  from {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.part3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Baskerville Old Face', serif;
}

.ww {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
}

.w1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: fit-content;
}

.wA {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-left: 80px;
}

.wB {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  line-height: 0.9;
  /* Adjust the line height as needed */
}

.wC {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 80px;
}

.w2 {
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 120px;
  margin-top: 90px;
}

.w2 img {
  border: 5px solid #fff6f2;
  /* Add a white border around the image */
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  /* Add transition for smooth animation */
}

.w2 img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  /* Increase the size by 10% */
}

.ww3 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 35px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 90px;
  margin-right: 90px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.part4 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Baskerville Old Face', serif;
}

.ee {
  color: white;
  font-size: 70px;
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: 70px;
  line-height: 0.9;
}

.part4 hr {
  border: none;
  /* Remove default border */
  height: 2px;
  /* Set height to 2px */
  background-color: white;
  /* Set background color to white */
}

.ee1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* Allow items to wrap into multiple rows */
  margin-left: 170px;
}

.eeA {
  background: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 30px;
  transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  /* Add transition effect */
}

.eeA p {
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 0.9;
  align-self: center;
}

.eeA:hover {
  background: black;
  /* Change background color on hover */
  color: white;
  /* Change font color on hover */
}

.part5 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Baskerville Old Face', serif;
}

.rr {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 27px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  align-self: center;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.rr p {
  font-size: 80px;
  margin-right: 120px;
}

.rr:hover {
  background: black;
  /* Change background color on hover */
  color: white;
  /* Change font color on hover */
}

.part6 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fff6f2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-family: 'Baskerville Old Face', serif;
}

.zz {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 70px;
  line-height: 0.9;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 60%;
}

.zz1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #232B2B;
  width: 40%;
  align-items: center;
}

.zz1 p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 250px;
}

.zz2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.box {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 155px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 75%, lightgrey 25%);
}

.box2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 85%, lightgrey 15%);
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.box3 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 65%, lightgrey 35%);
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 180px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.part7 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fff6f2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Baskerville Old Face', serif;
}

.ff {
  font-size: 70px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.line-container {
  width: 90%;
  height: 2px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Center the container horizontally */
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.small-square,
.big-square {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  border-radius: 40%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.small-square {
  left: calc(30% - 30px);
}

.big-square {
  left: calc(70% + 10px);
}

.ff1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.ff2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  /* Smooth transition effect */
}

.ff22 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  /* Smooth transition effect */
}

.ff2:hover,
.ff22:hover {
  transform: scale(1.15);
  /* Increase the size by 10% */
}

.ff3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  align-self: center;
}

.ff4 {
  font-size: 30px;
  align-self: center;
}

.ff5 {
  font: 20px;
}

.part8 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fff6f2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-family: 'Baskerville Old Face', serif;
}

.xx {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.image2 {
  margin-top: 150px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 200px;
}

.image3 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 350px;
}

.xx1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  line-height: 0.9;
  margin-left: 120px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.xx1:hover {
  color: #232B2B;
}

.xx3 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.part9 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-family: 'Baskerville Old Face', serif;
}

.vv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
}

.vv1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  line-height: 0.9;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.vv2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.vvA {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.vvA1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.image5 {
  height: 400px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.image5:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  /* Increase size by 10% on hover */
}

.vvA2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.p1a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 230px;
}

.p2a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 350px;
}

.part10 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-family: 'Baskerville Old Face', serif;
}

.mm1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 0.9;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.mm2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.image7 {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="part1">
    <div class="A1">
      <div class="tt">
        <p class="txt2">Creative Portfolio</p>
      </div>
      <div class="pv">
        <p class="txt">PREMIUM<br> VIRTUAL ASSIST</p>
        <p class="txt1">Elevating Your Efficiency</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="A1">
      <img src="{% static 'virtualAssist/bg1.jpg' %}" alt="Background Image" class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="logo-container">
      <img src="{% static 'virtualAssist/logo.jpeg' %}" alt="Logo" class="logo">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="part2">
    <img src="{% static 'virtualAssist/bg4.jpg' %}" alt="Circle Image" class="circle-image animate-slide-up">
    <div class="part2b">
      <div class="part2a">
        <div class="qq animate-slide-left-bg ">Introducing</div>
        <div class="q2 animate-slide-left-bg">Premium Virtual Assist stands out for its<br>professional, sophisticated, and efficient <br>approach, making it the go-to choice for clients in<br>need of exceptional virtual assistant services</div>
      </div>
      <div class="bg3 animate-slide-right">
        <img src="{% static 'virtualAssist/bg3.jpg' %}" alt="Background Image" class="image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="q3 animate-slide-up">
      WELCOME TO MY </br>
      PORTFOLIO
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="part3">
    <div class="ww">
      <div class="w1">
        <div class="wA">
          Hello, my name is
        </div>
        <div class="wB">
          MBOZYO <br> MBOMA
        </div>
        <div class="wC">
          A highly dynamic virtual assistant with 3 years of<br> experience in providing exceptional administrative,<br> customer and management support to businesses. I <br> thrive on multitasking and effectively prioritizing tasks to <br> ensure the
          best outcomes. My goal is to make your life <br> easier so you can put your energy into what matters <br> most. Some of my skills include;
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w2">
        <img src="{% static 'virtualAssist/bg5.jpeg' %}" alt="Background Image" class="image">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ww3">
      &#8226;CREATIVE &nbsp; &#8226;COMMUNICATION &nbsp; &#8226;PRODUCTIVE &nbsp; &#8226;ATTENTION TO DETAIL

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="part4">
    <div class="ee">
      WHY WORK <br> WITH ME ?
    </div>

    <div class="ee1">
      <div class="eeA">
        <p> CLIENT - CENTRIC<br> APPROACH</p>
        I AM COMMITTED TO <br> UNDERSTANDING AND <br> MEETING THE UNIQUE NEEDS <br> OF EACH CLIENT, ENSURING <br> THAT THE SUPPORT I <br> PROVIDE IS PERSONALIZED,<br> RELIABLE, AND TAILORED TO <br> OPTIMIZE THEIR SPECIFIC<br> OBJECTIVES, ULTIMATELY <br>        CONTRIBUTING TO THEIR<br> OVERALL SUCCESS.
      </div>
      <div class="eeA">
        <p>DEDICATED <br> INDIVIDUAL</p>
        I AM DEEPLY COMMITTED TO <br>PROVIDING TOP-NOTCH <br> SUPPORT AND ASSISTANCE TO <br>MY CLIENTS. WITH A STRONG<br> WORK ETHIC AND A PASSION <br>FOR HELPING OTHERS <br> SUCCEED, I GO ABOVE AND <br> BEYOND TO DELIVER <br> EXCEPTIONAL RESULTS AND
        <br> EXCEED EXPECTATIONS.
      </div>

      <div class="eeA">
        <p>HIGHLY <br>TEACHABLE</p>
        I AM QUICK TO GRASP NEW <br> AM QUICK TO GRASP <br> NEW CONCEPTS, TECHNOLOGIES,<br> AND METHODOLOGIES, AND I <br> ACTIVELY SEEK OUT<br> OPPORTUNITIES TO EXPAND MY <br> SKILLS. WITH A GROWTH <br>MINDSET, I AM ALWAYS OPEN TO<br> FEEDBACK, EAGER
        TO LEARN <br>NEW WAYS OF DOING THINGS, <br> AND READILY ADAPT TO<br> EVOLVING BEST PRACTICES.
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="part5">
    <div class="rr">
      <p> VISION </p>
      Empower clients through exceptional support, streamlining <br> operations, reducing workload, and enhancing productivity.<br> Contribute to client success with reliable, efficient, and personalized <br> assistance.
    </div>
    <div class="rr">
      <p> MISSION </p>
      &#8226; Deliver exceptional administrative and management support,<br> leveraging my experience and skills to streamline operations for<br> my clients.<br> &#8226; Reduce my clients’ workload and enhance productivity.<br> &#8226; Contribute to my
      clients’ overall success by providing reliable, <br> efficient, and personalized assistance.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="part6">
    <div class="zz">
      PERSONAL<br> SKILLS
      <div class="zz2">
        Graphic Design
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="zz2">
        Administrative Work
        <div class="box2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="zz2">
        Bookkeeping
        <div class="box3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="zz1">
      <p>1% better<br> everyday</p>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="part7">
    <div class="ff">
      EDUCATION BACKGROUND
    </div>
    <div class="line-container">
      <div class="small-square"></div>
      <div class="big-square"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="ff1">
      <div class="ff2">
        <p class="ff3">2021
          <p>
            <p class="ff4">&#x2022; High School</p>
            <p class="ff5"> In high school, I studied economics, pure <br> mathematics, geography, and general <br> studies, finding joy in the analytical and <br> social nature of economics and problem-<br> solving in pure mathematics. My excellence<br> in Economics
              earned me recognition as The<br> Best Economics Student in my class.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ff22">
        <p class="ff3">2025
          <p>
            <p class="ff4">&#x2022; Flight School</p>
            <p class="ff5"> My ambition for aviation parallels my<br> dedication to providing unparalleled <br> assistance to individuals. Combining my<br> love for flight with my commitment to<br> support, I aim to excel in both realms, <br> reaching new heights.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="part8">
    <div class="xx">
      <img src="{% static 'virtualAssist/bg7.jpg' %}" alt="Background Image" class="image2">
      <img src="{% static 'virtualAssist/bg6.jpg' %}" alt="Background Image" class="image3">
    </div>
    <div class="xx1">
      <p class="xx2">WORK <br> EXPERIENCE </p>
      <p class="xx3"> As a volunteer assistant for a non-governmental organization, I <br> immersed myself in a myriad of tasks, from managing emails to<br> coordinating events. I honed my skills in social media<br> management, editing, and fundraising, all while pursuing
        online<br> courses to expand my knowledge base. Transitioning to an<br> executive assistant role in a logistics company in 2021 provided <br> invaluable opportunities to apply my newfound skills and develop<br> further. However, my lifelong dream
        of aviation beckoned, leading<br> me to step away from full-time employment in 2023 to pursue<br> flight training and embrace the flexibility of virtual assistance. Each<br> step of my journey has shaped me into a versatile and capable<br> professional,
        driven by a passion for both service and flight.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="part9">
    <div class="vv">
      <p class="vv1">NOTABLE <br>PROJECTS</p>
      <p class="vv2">Due to client confidentiality, I'm unable to<br> display administrative and management work.<br> However, I can showcase my expertise in social<br> media management, graphic design, and<br> pamphlet creation. These examples highlight<br> my skills
        and creativity in areas that are not<br> subject to confidentiality agreements.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="vvA">
      <div class="vvA1">
        <img src="{% static 'virtualAssist/bg8.jpeg' %}" alt="Background Image" class="image5">
        <img src="{% static 'virtualAssist/bg9.jpeg' %}" alt="Background Image" class="image5">
      </div>
      <div class="vvA2">
        <p class="p1a">&#8226;PROJECT 01</p>
        <p class="p2a">&#8226;PROJECT 02</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="part10">
    <div class="mm">
      <p class="mm1">GRAPHIC DESIGN AND <br> PAMPHLET CREATION</p>
      <p class="mm2">Experienced in creating visually appealing graphic <br> designs, pamphlets, and PDF documents for various <br> clients. Utilized Canva to design engaging visuals and <br> layouts. Ensured consistency in branding and <br> messaging while meeting
        client objectives. Resulted in <br> increased brand visibility and enhanced<br> communication materials.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="{% static 'virtualAssist/bg10.jpg' %}" alt="Background Image" class="image7">
    </div>
  </div>



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>



</body>
```

You can answer by looking at this code

Comment: you can use [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/).